# How to pass multiple files(.nii format) as input file using python command line?

Tags: python, parsing, image-preprocessing, medical-imaging

I have a folder with 20 .nii files. Need to convert it into png, so using python nii2png.py for the same. [nii2png.py](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y7_m9QjcRQ-eiqmd-h_liT0mo26DU19B/view?usp=sharing) This is the file I am making changes in. Here are 2 files for your reference: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19mqPcHufOMyVGg4gT0IJDo0gKc1v4Baw/view?usp=sharing,%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3TWwl0HPRDXxH6ZkTolsn81sIQGvxqF/view?usp=sharing) these are 2 .nii files.
It has the following syntax:

```
!python nii2png.py -i <input file> -o <output folder>
```

How can I pass these 20 .nii files in a loop or some other solution?
This is the starting of the nii2png file:

```
import numpy, shutil, os, nibabel
import sys, getopt
import scipy.misc
import imageio
import argparse

def main(argv):
inputfile = ''
outputfile = ''

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:",["ifile=","ofile="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print('nii2png.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
    sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == '-h':
        print('nii2png.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
        sys.exit()
    elif opt in ("-i", "--input"):
        inputfile = arg
    elif opt in ("-o", "--output"):
        outputfile = arg

print('Input file is ', inputfile)
print('Output folder is ', outputfile)
```

Please ignore the indentation of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a better plan is to have a `-o` parameter for the output folder and have the rest of the command line be input file names, instead of using a single `-i` parameter.  Now you can specify things like `nli2png.py -o xxx a*.png b*.png left/c*.png`.

```
import numpy, shutil, os, nibabel
import sys
import scipy.misc
import imageio

def main(argv):
    if not argv:
        print('nii2png.py -o <outputfolder> <input> <input>...')
        sys.exit()

    grab = 0
    outputfolder = '.'
    inputfiles = []
    for arg in argv:
        if arg == '-o':
            grab = 1
        elif grab:
            outputfolder = arg
            grab = 0
        else:
            inputfiles.append(arg)

    print('Input files are ', inputfiles)
    print('Output folder is ', outputfolder)

main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: I do understand your thought process, but this solution did not work. I tried putting a loop in the code where each input file is taken and converted to png format, but it is not accepting the input files.

Comment: I have added the link to the python file, can you suggest changes in that?

Comment: My code works just fine.  What do you mean by "not accepting"?  What error, on which line?  You must be precise, since I don't have any of those images for testing.

Comment: You should change the code to ask about rotation and create the output folder outside of that loop.

Comment: Yes Thanks!! It worked."You should change the code to ask about rotation and create the output folder outside of that loop" -> will do this.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! For exact code: this is the link to the modified .py file : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1J2QkdzSQOiOA5AFSnExqg2qoLqA8S-AA?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use argparse.

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Convert files, syntax: nii2png.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--inputfiles', nargs='+', help='Paths of input files.')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--outputfolder', default='', help='Output folder.')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(f'Input files: {args.inputfiles}')
    print(f'Output folder: {args.outputfolder}')
    
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```